# mysql - how to find time difference based on high to low reached time

Tags: mysql

I have a table called water_tank,

```
select * from tank_id; 


id  unique_tankId  highLevel    lowLevel
1     1             75          50
2     2             80          55


select * from water_tank where tabkId=1; 


id  tankId  level   serverTimeStamp
1     1     50      2016-06-28 12:00:01
2     1     60      2016-06-28 12:59:01
3     1     85      2016-06-28 13:00:01
4     1     89      2016-06-28 13:30:01
5     1     90      2016-06-28 14:00:01
6     1     100     2016-06-28 15:00:01
7     1     10      2016-06-28 16:00:01
8     1     20      2016-06-28 16:30:01
9     1     28      2016-06-28 17:00:01
10    1     50      2016-06-29 12:00:01
11    1     60      2016-06-29 12:59:01
12    1     67      2016-06-29 13:00:01
13    1     75      2016-06-29 15:00:01
14    1     90      2016-06-29 16:00:01
15    1     95      2016-06-29 17:00:01
16    1     98      2016-06-29 18:00:01
17    1     100     2016-06-29 19:30:01
18    1     24      2016-06-29 20:00:01
..      ..  ..      ...
..      ..  ..      ...
```

Note : **id is AI and tankId is foreign key**

I want to find time difference from high(level >=75) level serverTimeStamp to low(level <50)level serverTimeStamp using mysql query.

Expecting output :

```
timeDiffInHour      highReachedTime         cleanedTime
3                   2016-06-28 13:00:01     2016-06-28 16:00:01
5                   2016-06-29 15:30:01     2016-06-29 20:00:01
..                  ...                     ...
```

Someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: ___tankId is unique id___ Then as the Swordsman said **There can be only one**??

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, check the updated question

Comment: I think **tankId** is the aggregator (group by) column. Right?

Comment: @FredericoFalcao pls check my updated question.

Comment: **tank_id** cannot be primary key in table **water_tank** since it's not unique. It is a `foreign key` in table water_tank referencing table : **tank_id** column: **unique_TankId**

Comment: ya you are right. I updated in  my question,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT tankId, 
MIN(serverTimeStamp) lowReachedTime, 
b.highReachedTime,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(serverTimeStamp),b.highReachedTime) timeDiffinHour
FROM tankId a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT tankId, MAX(serverTimeStamp) highReachedTime 
   FROM water_tank
   WHERE level > 75
   GROUP BY tankId
) b ON b.tankId = a.tankId
WHERE level < 50
GROUP BY a.tankId
```

Comment: SELECT tankId, MAX(serverTimeStamp) highReachedTime 
   FROM water_tank
   WHERE level > 75
   GROUP BY tankId here you will get one value then how it will work?

Comment: With this sub-query you'll get one value per **tankId** for all the **tankId**s whose **level** is greater than 75, and within the group of similar **tankId**s you'll get  the maximum time (i.e. the time most in the future) of **serverTimeStamp**.

Comment: You're expected output is *unclear* to me. What is the unique column there? How is **cleanedTime** calculated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116097/discussion-between-frederico-falcao-and-mmmms).